# How does Spring Web require Apache HttpComponents (HTTPClient) without declaring it as a dependency?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

In the Spring ([Spring Web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web)) documentation for [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.html) it states that,

> NOTE: Requires Apache HttpComponents 5.1 or higher, as of Spring 6.0.

When I look at the code for [HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java) I can also clearly see corresponding [imports](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/efb6abc43f550c2be20f39ad9ce65346ee5ebd65/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java#L26C8-L26C53) & [references](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/efb6abc43f550c2be20f39ad9ce65346ee5ebd65/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/http/client/HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory.java#L98C34-L98C34) to [Apache HttpComponents HTTPClient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5).

However when I look at [Spring Web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web)'s (maven) dependency [declaration](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web/6.0.11) (or its [POM](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-web/6.0.11/spring-web-6.0.11.pom)) I don't see [Apache HttpComponents HTTPClient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5) declared as a dependency.

Just to add more context here (for folks who may miss the comments section where I clarified this), shouldn't [Apache HttpComponents HTTPClient](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents.client5/httpclient5) library be declared at least as an optional dependency (`<optional>true</optional>`) of [Spring Web](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web)? Why (or how) is it not even declared (let alone marked as optional) in its POM?

How does this work? Does someone know & can help share pointers?

Below for example is the dependency tree for an older version `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.7.0`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------< dcm.dev.util:maven-dependency-resolver-tool >-------------
[INFO] Building maven-dependency-resolver-tool 1.0
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ maven-dependency-resolver-tool ---
[INFO] dcm.dev.util:maven-dependency-resolver-tool:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.8:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.20.0:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.7:compile
[INFO]    |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.2:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.1.1:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.10:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.10:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.10:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]    |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]    |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.10.8:compile
[INFO]    |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.10.8:compile
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]       +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.10:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Update (07/21/23)**:
Thanks to @Slaw, I realized Spring switched to Gradle with 2.3 release (June 2020), which may explain how the build works (since it ***is*** declared as an optional dependency in the gradle build).

So could the [org.springframework.build.optional-dependencies](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/efb6abc43f550c2be20f39ad9ce65346ee5ebd65/buildSrc#optional-dependencies) plugin have a play in this?

Thanks

Comment: If you use it you need to declare it yourself. Spring has support for many many different frameworks, the fact that they support something doesn't mean they pull every dependency in (they do during building but it is a compileOnly/optional dependency for usage).

Comment: See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/efb6abc43f550c2be20f39ad9ce65346ee5ebd65/spring-web/spring-web.gradle#L48C59-L48C59

Comment: @M.Deinum From what I understand, I don't think that's how maven works (or there is a gap in my understanding). Setting aside Spring here for a minute, if a source code in a maven project refers _directly_ to a library in its code by importing & using to it then the library _has_ to be declared as a dependency in its POM. Now it could be classified as _optional_ (`<optional>true</optional>`) in which case any project that depends on the aforementioned project might have to explicitly declare the optional library as a dependency in its POM if it wants to use it. But that's not what we see here.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you, I did see it. Though I am not very familiar with gradle, I noticed at least there it made perfect sense since it was declared as optional dependency, which seems correct since if a project doesn't use client-side HTTP it will _not need_ the Apache HTTPClient library & forcing it would be a bloat. But the maven one did not even declare it. That's the confusion.

Comment: I think that's due to the POM being generated by Gradle when publishing the artifacts (via Gradle). Because the POM is not actually being used to _build_ the project (that's Gradle's job), it only declares enough for other projects to _use_ it. But that's all speculation on my part.

Comment: @Slaw Thank you. Btw I didn't know Gradle can generate the maven POM!

Comment: Check out the [Maven Publish Plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html) (it talks about POM generation). Also, note it looks like the `optional` configuration is added by a [custom Gradle plugin](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/tree/efb6abc43f550c2be20f39ad9ce65346ee5ebd65/buildSrc#optional-dependencies).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254618/discussion-between-lmk-and-slaw).

Answer (score 0):

In the Spring framework, some components may have optional dependencies that are not explicitly declared in the project's POM (Project Object Model) file. Instead, these dependencies are conditionally loaded at runtime based on certain conditions. This mechanism is achieved through Spring's use of conditional dependencies and dynamic class loading.

When you see the documentation for `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` stating that it requires Apache HttpComponents 5.1 or higher, and you can see corresponding imports and references to Apache HttpComponents `HTTPClient` in the code, it means that the class uses features from Apache HttpComponents.

However, Apache HttpComponents is not explicitly declared as a direct dependency in the project's POM for `spring-boot-starter-web`. Instead, it might be an optional or transitive dependency.

In your provided dependency tree, you can see that `spring-web` and `spring-webmvc` are the direct dependencies for the `spring-boot-starter-web` artifact. But, if you look closely, you can find that `spring-web` has a transitive dependency on org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient.

So, the actual declaration of Apache HttpComponents HTTPClient as a dependency is hidden within the transitive dependencies of `spring-web`, which is a direct dependency of `spring-boot-starter-web`.

This approach allows Spring to maintain a more lightweight and flexible framework, as users can choose to include or exclude specific features by managing the dependencies accordingly. It also avoids version conflicts with other libraries that might have different requirements for Apache HttpComponents versions.

Comment: Not sure but feels a bit like a ChatGPT answer? That being said if it was a transitive dependency it would automatically be included, only `optional` dependencies aren't automatically included.

Comment: @M.Deinum I agree, it feels a little 'ChatGPT'ish ;-) Also the following line is not even true if one actually looks at the snippet in the question, 
> _But, if you look closely, you can find that spring-web has a transitive dependency on org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient._

Comment: @Massnissa BELAID can you please elaborate on this line in your answer?, 
> _But, if you look closely, you can find that spring-web has a transitive dependency on org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient._

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, that's the question. Shouldn't Apache HTTPClient library be defined as an optional dependency of Spring Web? Why is it not even declared (let alone marked as optional) in the POM of Spring Web.

Comment: `[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.2.0:tree (default-cli) @ maven-dependency-resolver-tool ---
[INFO] dcm.dev.util:maven-dependency-resolver-tool:jar:1.0
[INFO] \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]    |  \- (org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.20:compile - omitted for duplicate)
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO]       \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.20:compile
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]`

Comment: @Massnissa BELAID Above is the dependency tree for spring-web, where do you see `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient` there?

Comment: It is an optional dependency of Spring Web which is exactly why you don't see it! Opotional dependencies aren't included!.

Comment: @M.Deinum Sorry I missed your last response. I didn't quite get why optional dependencies aren't included. Are you referring to the decision taken by Spring team a while back to not include optional dependencies in the Maven POM (even though its included in the Gradle build used to build the artifacts)?

Comment: @M.Deinum I came to know of the above decision after I raised an issue [#30943](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30943) on Spring. The problem is the PR [#23486](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23486) that was meant to track & provide an alternate approach to convey this dependency metadata was abruptly closed with ["We didn't find proper ways to express that information in our build"](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/23486#issuecomment-607445982). This leaves us with the original issues including mine now in limbo.

Comment: What limbo? Even if it would have been an `optional` dependency you wouldn't see it in a dependency tree, so even if it would be there you wouldn't see it. Unless you would actually read the `pom.xml`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Its true that `maven-dependency-plugin` will not show `optional` dependencies in the tree (I remember they used to show that, but not sure & surely not any more) but its also true that maven does show the optional dependencies when one looks at it online on maven central, which is what I always do. Here is an [example](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.netty/netty-all/4.1.50.Final). The limbo part is the underlying requirement of publishing the dependency metadata in some way which is what both my issue & the other ones listed in my previous comment requested for.

Comment: @M.Deinum Perhaps you may have some thoughts on my [last](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/30943#issuecomment-1652311985) comment..